# understanding final layer of output for classification problem BCELoss vs CrossEntropyLoss

Tags: pytorch

I'm making a binary image classifier. I'm just using a pretrained model to start and change the last fully connected layer to predict between 2 classes, which I'm told requires the last layer to be the number of features and then the number of classes.

```
    model = models.resnet18(pretrained=True, progress=True)
    num_ftrs = model.fc.in_features
    model.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 2)
```

I'm using a batch size of 6 so my model predicted probability of one batch is like so

```
tensor([[-0.4717, -0.2232],
        [-0.6481, -0.2630],
        [-0.2007, -0.1596],
        [ 0.0277, -0.0759],
        [-0.3314, -0.1211],
        [-0.1722, -0.5304]],
```

and my ground truth labels are `torch.tensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])`

For BCELoss I get an error that says

```
Using a target size (torch.Size([6])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([6, 2])) is deprecated. Please ensure they have the same size.
```

However, for `CrossEntropyLoss` this works just fine.

The same happens with the example below

```
outputs = torch.randn(3, 2, 1)
target = torch.empty(3, 1, dtype=torch.long).random_(2)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction='mean')
print(outputs)
print(target)
loss = criterion(outputs, target)
print(loss)


outputs = torch.randn(3, 2, 1)
target = torch.empty(3, 1, dtype=torch.long).random_(2)

criterion = torch.nn.BCELoss()
print(outputs)
print(target)
loss = criterion(outputs, target)
print(loss)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because ,if using BCE , the last layer should have only single neuron i.e

```
model = models.resnet18(pretrained=True, progress=True)
num_ftrs = model.fc.in_features
model.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 1)
```

And when using CE,

```
model = models.resnet18(pretrained=True, progress=True)
num_ftrs = model.fc.in_features
model.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 2)
```